# Getting wrong results when trying to write out to a file in c++

Tags: c++

So my objective for this program is to read input from a file and output results to a file based on calculations done to the info that was read. The problem I keep getting is that I keep getting the same results in the output file.

Comment: Cool story bro. What's the question?

Comment: Umm... `if (0 > Years <= 10)`. This isn't Python. That code evaluates to `(0 > Years) <= 10`. Since `0 > Years` is always either 0 or 1, it's also always `<= 10`.

Comment: My question is that is there something wrong with the way that I did computations in my compute method. I keep getting the same results for salary in the output. So for some reason the variable sal in the method doesn't get overwritten.

Comment: So what results do you get and what results do you expect to get?

Comment: So the input file consists of four lines of code with different numbers. The output file will calculate a salary based on one line, so 4 in total. But I keep the same salary amount in the output file for each line.

Comment: `basepay*.05` `basepay*.10`... probably won't do what you expected

Comment: It looks to me like this won't print anything because `print` is not called. In fact it won't even run since it's missing `main`.

Comment: I don't see merit.h.

Comment: @user34660 This program actually uses "employee.h". The file "merit.h" is a file I was using for another program.

Comment: I see you corrected the source. In "employee::Compute" what is "if (0 > Years <= 10)" trying to do?

Comment: That checks if the value "years" is between 0 and 10. But I'm seeing that it makes sense to just put (years <=10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First note that I am using Visual Studio and pre-compiled headers so my header configuration is a bit different.

When I compiled your code the compiler sure warned me that using "int" would be a problem. I always remove warnings unless I am sure I don't need to and I don't ignore warnings unless I am sure I can safely.

For "employee.h" I have:

```
#pragma once
using namespace std;

class employee
{
public:

    void readData(ifstream& inf);
    //Precondition: File must exist, be accessible, and have the appropriate contents

    //Postcondition: The contents in the file are assigned to a variable. 

    void Compute(double basepay);
    //Precondition: basepay = $800
    //Postcondition: Salary is found using the basepay plus the three other basepays percentages. 

    void print(ofstream& outf) const;
    //Precondition:  The new values (ID and salary) must be updated and accessible. 
    //Postcondition: The ID and salary must be displayed in an output file. The salary must be in the proper format.  

    employee();
    //Precondition:  The variables ID, Job_class, Years, Ed, and sal must have been created already. 
    //Postcondition: the variables ID, Job_class, Years, Ed, and sal are all set to zero. 

private:

    int ID;
    int Job_class;
    int Years;
    int Ed;
    double sal;

};
```

Note that "sal" is a double.

For "employee.cpp" I have:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "employee.h"
using namespace std;


void employee::readData(ifstream& inf)
{
    inf >> ID >> Job_class >> Years >> Ed;
}

void employee::Compute(double basepay)
{
    //int extra = .01;
    //int bp1 = 0;
    //int bp2 = 0;
    //int bp3 = 0;
    double extra = .01;
    double bp1 = 0;
    double bp2 = 0;
    double bp3 = 0;

    if (Job_class == 1)
    {
        bp1 = basepay*.05;
    }
    if (Job_class == 2)
    {
        bp1 = basepay*.10;
    }
    if (Job_class == 3)
    {
        bp1 = basepay*.20;
    }

    if (Years > 0 && <= 10)
    {
        bp2 = basepay*.05;
    }
    if (Years> 10)
    {
        bp2 = basepay*(.05 + extra);
    }

    if (Ed == 1)
    {
        bp3 = 0;
    }
    if (Ed == 2)
    {
        bp3 = basepay * 05;
    }
    if (Ed == 3)
    {
        bp3 = basepay*.12;
    }
    if (Ed == 4)
    {
        bp3 = basepay*.20;
    }

    sal = basepay + bp1 + bp2 + bp3;
}


void employee::print(ofstream& outf) const
{
    outf << ID << setw(15) << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2) << "$ " <<
        sal << endl;
}

employee::employee()  // default constructor
{
    ID = 0;
    Job_class = 0;
    Years = 0;
    Ed = 0;
    sal = 0.0;
}
```

For the main I have:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
using namespace std;
#include "employee.h"

int main()
{
    double basepay = 800;
    employee emp;
    ifstream inf;
    inf.open("G:\\Temporary\\employee.txt");
    ofstream outf;
    outf.open("G:\\Temporary\\employeeout.txt");

    if (!inf)
    {
        cout << " *** Input file does not exist! *** " << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    outf << "ID #" << setw(20) << "Salary" << endl;
    outf << "****************************" << endl;

    while (!inf.eof())
    {
        emp.readData(inf);
        emp.Compute(basepay);
        emp.print(outf);
    }

    inf.close();
    outf.close();
    return 0;
}
```

For "employee.txt" I have:

```
1078 2 12 3
1070 3 10 4
```

Note that there are no commas.

For "employeeout.txt" I have:

```
ID #              Salary
****************************
1078             $ 1024.00
1070             $ 1160.00
1070             $ 1160.00
```

Note that the program is reading the last line twice. I did not fix that; I think it is a matter of personal preference how to handle that so you can do it your way.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. Quick question. In the compute method. In the if statements, you used two equal signs. How come it doesn't work when just one is used?

Comment: I used two because your source code used two (look again) but two must always be used until you learn more. Two equal signs is a logical operator and one is an assignment operator. Please refer to the documentation and to books. Note that I fixed the "if" that I asked about previously. You should study that.

Answer (score 0):

Integer rounding. That seems to be a problem. Switch from using `int` to using `double`.